# Marking scenario test as skipped when background operation fails

Tags: karate, web-api-testing

I want to mark scenario as skipped in case of any fail in Background. I have the following structure in feature file:

```
Background:
  * call read('classpath:path/to/reusable.feature@ParticularScenario')
  ...

Scenario: That one I want to skip if background call statement fails
  Given ... 
  When ...
  Then ...
```

I tried to use `* if () karate.abort()` expression in background after call statement but it does nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend this and strongly urge you to re-structure your tests.

But here is a possible solution. I say again, I don't like this at all.

```
Background:
* def error = false
* eval
"""
try {
  var result = karate.call('reusable.feature');
  karate.set(result);
} catch (e) {
  karate.log('background failed:', e);
  karate.set('error', true);
}
"""

Scenario:
* if (error) karate.abort()
```

But otherwise, Karate is not designed for this, sorry.